# Lower integral of Dirichlet's Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

**Claim:**

The lower integral of Dirichlet's function is $0$. Consider the set

$$A=\left\{ \int_a^b s_n\mid s_n \text{ is simple function and }s_n\leq f \text{ on }[a,b]\right\}.$$

**Attempt:**

Suppose $0$ is not the lower integral, then there must be some simple function $k$ s.t. $$\underline{\int}_a^b k(x)>0$$ I showed that this implies $k(x)>0$ on some interval of $[a,b]$ by examine its aggregate sum. This is where I cannot proceed.

What should I do next?

Comment: Do you need to use that to prove, because there is a way simpler way to do it.

Comment: Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: I know that for your specific question it doesn't matter this observation, but there are two functions called Dirichlet function:

[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) and [2](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/4/txe3ba4s.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Irrationals are dense in $\mathbb R$, thus for any interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ there will be found irrationals there.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the Darboux integral then the lower integral is $0$. This is so because independently from the specific division of  $[a,b]$ the infimum of $f$ is always $0$ over the sub intervals because there will be irrationals in the sub intervals. The upper integral is $1$ for there will be rationals in the sub intervals.